# Geeknote installation

Tags: python

I am trying to install Geeknote from source using the instructions from https://www.geeknote.me/documentation/. When I get to line 7 of the instructions in the terminal, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent last call):
File "setup.py", line 10, in module
from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

What do I need to do to remedy this error? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is line 7 of the instructions? I went to check out the link and the lines are not numbered and I am not sure how you count lines (e.g. do the commented lines count?).

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`

Answer (score 0):

As @eyoung suggested, use `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools`, it should do the trick.